# How to get queryset data in django which picked from two range date calender forms (date_from - date_to)?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

i've tried to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04L0BbAcCpQ&t=5133s (minutes: 2:10:27)
as creator said, to access the date directly, we need to code double underscore as "created__date". That's because mentioned in django documentation perfectly the same way. this still didn't get me result as the creator had. Meanwhile, when i disabled my filter (qs = Sale.objects.filter(date=date_from) in views.py) and print it as object it's worked. Also when i moved queryset code a head from if block code, it's print perfectly compiled from qs = Sale.objects.all() and gave me result all of 3 data of it.

#here is the views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Sale
from .forms import SalesSearchForm
# from django.views.generic.list import ListView

# Create your views here.

def home_view(request):
    form = SalesSearchForm(request.POST or None)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        date_from = request.POST.get('date_from')
        date_to = request.POST.get('date_to')
        chart_type = request.POST.get('chart_type')
        print(date_from, date_to, chart_type)

        # qs = Sale.objects.all()
        #atau bisa diganti dengan filter tertentu untuk seleksi data yang di inginkan:
        qs = Sale.objects.filter(created__date=date_from)
        obj = Sale.objects.get(id=2)
        print(qs)
        print(obj)

    # hello = 'hello world from sales/views.py'
    context = {
        # 'hello': hello,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'sales/home.html', context)
```

here is the model.py (pay attention at Class Sale):

```
from django.db import models
from products.models import Product
from customers.models import Customer
from profiles.models import Profile
from django.utils import timezone
from .utils import generate_code
from django.shortcuts import reverse
# Create your models here.

class Position(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.FloatField(blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"id: {self.id}, product: {self.product.name}, quantity: {self.quantity}"
class Sale(models.Model):
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
    total_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Sales for the amount of ${self.total_price}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('sales:detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})  

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.transaction_id == "":                   # jika transaksi sama dengan blank
            self.transaction_id = generate_code()       # maka kode transaksi id digenerate dgn fungsi '***'
        if self.created is None:                         # jika created = none
            self.created = timezone.now()               # maka created = timezone.now
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_positions(self):            #sebuah custom method untuk mendapatkan semua data di class position related ke sale object
        return self.positions.all()     #harus refere ke manytomany field (field positions)

class CSV(models.Model):
    file_name = models.FileField(upload_to='csvs')
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file_name)
```

Here is the forms.py:

```
from django import forms

CHART_CHOICES = (
    ('#1', 'Bar chart'),
    ('#2', 'Pie chart'),
    ('#3', 'Line chart'),
)

class SalesSearchForm(forms.Form):
    date_from = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    date_to = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    chart_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHART_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0):

hy thanks for trying to figured out. I've been working to solve this for almost 2 days. and my solution is worked!
the problem is when i tried to select the date from the forms for the "between date" is not working. it just shows when i picked exact date input. So i read the django documentation over again. and i change the code from this (views.py):

```
qs = Sale.objects.filter(created__date=date_from)
```

to this:

```
qs = Sale.objects.filter(created__range=(date_from, date_to))
```

That's it! Hopefully anyone find this helpful. thanks!